# WordPress - How to add something after first paragraph in get_the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone tell me how to change my code to work with get_the_content() function? I was trying to change "the_content" to "get_the_content", but it's not working.

```
//Insert ads after first paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
     function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

 $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

 if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
  return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 1, $content );
 }

 return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
 $closing_p = '</p>';
 $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
 foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

  if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
   $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
  }

  if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
   $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
  }
 }

 return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Comment: Check this out
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-insert-ads-within-your-post-content-in-wordpress/

Comment: it also work only on the_content. When I show my post with get_the_content, nothing happen